# Where should I place the notorious '+c'?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

Consider the following proof -

$$I=\int \sin (\ln x)dx\\\iff I=\sin(\ln x)x-\int\frac{ \cos (\ln x) }{x}\cdot  {x} dx \\\iff I=x\sin (\ln x)-\int\cos(\ln x)dx\\\iff I=x\sin(\ln x )-[x\cos(\ln x)+\int \sin(\ln x)dx]\\\iff I=x(\sin(\ln x)-\cos(\ln x))-I\\\iff2I=x(\sin(\ln x)-\cos(\ln x))\\ \iff I=\frac{x(\sin(\ln x)-\cos(\ln x))}{2}$$

Now this is clearly slightly wrong as I missed out '+c'. My question is in which step should I write the '+c' ?

Comment: The end is fine in this case... for $C/2$ is still a constant... the +C is notation for modulo a constant.

Comment: You should add the $C$ as soon as the last integral sign is gone.

Comment: Constants of integration appear at every step of integration, i.e. on lines $2$ ,$4$ and $5$. They need to be carried, of course so you will get a constant in every line.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy but that doesn't really make sense because all I did in the last step was divide by two, how does the +c creep in ?

Comment: @LucyferZedd One constant each comes from the two partial integration step and another one comes from
$$\int \sin(\ln x) dx = I + c_3$$
In the end you can add all of them to a new constant.

Comment: @AlexR Partial integration does not create new constants

Comment: @Darksonn partial integration requires you to integrate factors. $\int 1 dx = x+c$ so it's $\sin(\ln x)(x+c)$ and so on.

Comment: @AlexR When you perform partial integration there's still another integral together with the constant, so the integral absorbs the constant.

Comment: @Darksonn Care to elaborate what you are talking about? Either I don't understand you, or it's wrong.

Comment: @AlexR Partial integration is using the identity $$\int f(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(x)g(x)+\int f'(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ If we had a constant inserted like this $$\int f(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(x)g(x)+\int f'(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx+C$$ then the integral on RHS would absorb that constant and it would be redundant

Comment: @Darksonn The fact that the constant will be absorbed (or otherwise modified) is no justification to say that it isn't there. Else you could conclude that we may leave it out completely since it may be chosen to become $0$.

Comment: @AlexR What I mean is that it dosen't make any sense to introduce the constants at partial integration since they might as well not be written because of the integrals.

Comment: @Darksonn This is getting lengthy. Using the same argument you might as well omit the entire constant, or only put it in the last line "appearing magically" because the FTC guarantees you that if you found _one_ integral, all others are given by adding a constant. Thus you may chose all constants in the solution process to become $0$ as you like and you're done. This will not help you with the understanding and can get you into trouble when working with ODEs for example because there constants of integration may get integrated again and BOOM you forgot a whole dimension of solution space.

Comment: @AlexR I do agree with the third constant, and I'm aware of the integration of constants, what I'm saying is just that with $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and $C+\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ for some constant $C$ will always give you the same result (except the constant might be a different one, but a constant nonethelesss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you do an integration by parts, you should add a constant $c_1$ to the equation, but you repeated the integration by parts so you would get another constant $c_2$ which gets *absorbed* by the earlier $c_1$. And when you finally solve for the required integral, you'll have the constants piled up on one side which then equal some new constant $c$. But to avoid the annoying $c_1$ and $c_2$ along the way, you can just add the constant all the way at the end here.

Comment: How does integration by parts add a constant?

Comment: in which line do you suggest?

Comment: $\int (fg)' dx = \int (f'g + g'f) dx \implies fg + c = \int f'g dx + \int g'f dx$

Comment: @LucyferZedd Conclusively (as my comment says) the lines where (partial) integration occurs are $2,4$ and $5$.

Comment: Agreed with @AlexR, you should add $c_1$ in line $2$ and then another $c_2$ in line $4$, then you combine them and call the result $c$ which you move around to whichever side you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

When you have $I=\int\text{something }\mathrm dx$ and you then have $I=blabla+\int\text{the same something }\mathrm dx$ then those two integral values are not neccesarily the same, in that they might differ by the constant so when you transform the new integral into $I$ you should actually make it into $I+C$

$$I=x(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x)-(I+C)$$
$$I+(I+C)=x(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x)$$
$$2I+C=x(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x)$$
$$I+C=\frac{x(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x)}2$$
$$I=\frac{x(\sin\ln x-\cos\ln x)}2+C$$